# Add EnvironmentPurpose to existing TtmCdTopologyType

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

When setting up my development environment I added only a 'Staging' Environment Purpose to my Topology type.

Now I like to update this Topology type and add 'Live' also as an Environment Purpose.

My current TopologyTypes looks like:

[image]

When I am trying to add the Live Environment Purpose with the following command:

```
Set-TtmCdTopologyType -Id IntranetStagingAndLive -EnvironmentPurposes Staging,Live
```

I get the following error:

```
Set-TtmCdTopologyType : Property 'EnvironmentPurposes' of the item of type 'CdTopologyTypeData' with id 'IntranetStagingAndLive' can not be updated, because item is used by item of type 'CdTopologyData' with id 'DevTopology'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-TtmCdTopologyType -Id IntranetStagingAndLive -EnvironmentPurposes Staging,Li ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...logyTypeCommand:SetCdTopologyTypeCommand) [Set-TtmCdTopologyType], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.SetCdTopologyTypeCommand
```

To be sure I unpublished all content published to the Target Type and removed the Business Process Type from the publication.

The description of the command doesn't say anything about that adding an Environment Purpose isn't possible:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tried this, but what I think you'll need to do is:

1. Create a new Topology Type that contains both of the purposes that you now need ('Staging' and 'Live') (e.g. `Add-TtmCdTopologyType -Name NewIntranetStagingAndLive -EnvironmentPurposes @("Staging", "Live")`)
2. Update the existing Topology to use this new Topology Type and specify the CD Environment for each of the purposes (e.g. `Set-TtmCdTopology -Id DevTopology -CdTopologyTypeId NewIntranetStagingAndLive -CdEnvironmentIds @("StagingEnvironmentId","LiveEnvironmentId")`)
3. Update the Business Process Type to use the new Topology Type too (setting the values for the new 'Live' purpose)
4. Delete the old Topology Type (e.g. `Remove-TtmCdTopologyType IntranetStagingAndLive`)

As I say, I've not tested this but it's certainly what I'd recommend trying next.

Comment: It may be worth to call out how you have passed multiple values for Purposes and EnvironmentIds using @(). TopMan does give you relevant error message when the parameters are passed correctly.

Comment: Indeed, you are effectively defining a new Topology Type (consisting of more CD Environments). That’s what you should do in TTM too: define the new Type, define new Topologies based on the new Type, define a new BPT and switch your Publications to use that one.

Comment: Ah, okay. So Peter will need to create a new Topology, rather than updating the existing one (step 2 in my list). Is that correct, @RickPannekoek?

Comment: That may be the easiest route, yes.

Comment: I resolved it by deleting all needed related configuration (so I also had to remove the Ttm Environment) and create it again, but your solution sounds a little bit faster. But the answer is that it is not possible to 'update' and existing Topology.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I’m surprised and saddened to hear that you had to delete all of the related configuration (I.e. the existing Staging CD Environment). Surely this can’t be an unusual scenario - needing to add an extra Purpose? I’m interested to hear whether SDL have this as expected behaviour or whether there’s something special in your setup that necessitated it. Glad it’s sorted now though.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that you cannot change a Topology Type if you already have Topologies of that Type (regardless if you published items or not).

If you delete the Topology with ID ‘DevTopology’ (and any other Topology using that Topology Type), you should be able to change the Topology Type.

In general, if you change a Topology Type, you are effectively defining a new one and therefore it is best to create a new Topology Type next to the existing one.

Comment: But because that Topology is also in use by the TtmEnvironments it is not possible to delete that Topology right away.I resolved it by deleting all dependendt configurations and create the Topology(type) again.

Comment: What does “the Topology is in use by the TtmEnvironments” mean, exactly? AFAIK, a Topology uses CD Environments (and a single CD Environment can be used in multiple Topologies), not vice versa.